# Using the symfony/dotenv bundle in production

Tags: symfony, security

The documentation refers to the [The Twelve Factors](https://www.12factor.net/) principles for why sensitive configuration shouldn't be stored in files, however it makes sense mostly for SaaS. I wonder if it is secure to use the symfony/dotenv bundle in software which users deploy themselves on their systems.

Comment: From a security point of view, it is no problem.  There is a bit of extra overhead in that the .env file will be loaded and parsed on each request.  Probably not enough to be noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are using .env file on production services in our company and there is not much overhead according to code execution profiling. While it's ok in our environment, it could be not in yours.

I'm pretty sure its secure enough to use dotenv component to load variables from .env file, since it does not provide any interface to interact with itself.

We are also storing docker specific environment variables in this file, so in the end it's like old parameters.yaml configuration file for the whole project.